# How to get CGridView for the SQL Query result?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cgridview

I try the following query, and which produces an array,

```
$user = Yii::app()->reg->createCommand()
->select('studentID')
->from('Students')
->queryAll();
```

But, when i try to get the value of the query in CGridview, Im getting the error,

```
Property "CDbCommand.0" is not defined.
```

here is the code for gridview,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'students-grid',
'dataProvider'=> new CSqlDataProvider($user),
));
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use 'keyfield' to avoid the error, Undefined index 'id'
and keyfield = name of the selected column

```
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
'totalItemCount'=>(int) $count1,
'keyField' => 'studentID',
'pagination'=>array( 'pageSize'=>30, ),));
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: 
In Your $model  define the data:

```
public function newsearch(){
$query = "Your Query";
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
         'totalItemCount'=>$count));
}
```

In your Controller Action:

```
$model = new model or assigned model;
 //Your Logic //
$this->render('viewname',array('model'=>$model));
```

And in your view file call this function:

```
'dataProvider'=> $model->newsearch(),
```

Remember your dataprovider attributes only depends on your query.Use alias and call in the gridview columns.

Comment: @thnks for your help, also i have few more doubts, i have 5 models, now im trying to generate a report by sql query, which includes all the 5 models. i use a form without model i.e, report.php, from the form input, i generate a query, so now how to use it?? may i use the above code in any1 of the models??

Comment: you can assing the function in any model and pass that model in your controller render function.By this functionality you can call that model search function in your Cgridview dataprovider.

Comment: I got the following error??
    Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\yiiroot\framework\web\CPagination.php on line 151

Comment: Here you execute 2 same queries, one full second with limit, is absolutl not optimized solution.

Comment: in this sqldataprovider, how can I add a column for checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`CSqlDataProvider` constructor](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider#__construct-detail), first param should be a string containing a SQL query, or a `CdbCommand`, but $user is an `array`.

You should try :

```
$command = Yii::app()->reg->createCommand()
  ->select('studentID')
  ->from('Students');
```

And :

```
'dataProvider'=> new CSqlDataProvider($command)
```

PS: did you try to use [`CActiveDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) ?

Comment: thnx alot soju, actually im trying to use cgridview, by dynamic queries, thats why, i try CSqlDataProvider. but still i have an error, undefined index 'id'. when trying ur steps

Comment: can i use CActiveDataProvider for dynamic queries, by user??

Comment: we only use sql data provider if we have very complex query.We should try to utilize the CActive DataProvider. it saves time and efforts.

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena, how to use CSqlDataProvider in my case. I have a dynamic query, and i want to list the result in CGridview.. thnx for ur reply

Comment: that was in gridview, now i changed somehing, as per  @SudhanshuSaxena's post. NOW im getting fatal error. "Unsupported operand type in CPagination.php"

Comment: undefined ID is from CSqlDataProvider.php page

Answer (score 0):

This is the code,

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT student_name FROM  smartrea_srkreg.Students";
$count=Yii::app()->reg->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
'totalItemCount'=>$count,
'pagination'=>array(
'pageSize'=>30,
 ),
));
var_dump($dataProvider);
?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'students-grid',
'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider, 
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of the controller. Pass this dataprovider to the template

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Students',
             array(
            'criteria'=>array(                        
            'select'=>'t.studentID'
        )));
```

In the template file paste the code below:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'subject-grid',
   'dataProvider'=>$model,
   'columns'=>array(
       'studetID',
        array(
           'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
   ),
));
```

May this help you :)

Comment: thanks for your reply rohit, but i want to do with CSqlDataProvider, coz, i want the gridview by dynamic queries.